# Typeset not found error in ksh

Tags: unix, typeset

I have written a statement like typeset -l target_tbl. I am getting an error that typeset : not found.

I ran the same statement on prompt. It executed successfully. I am getting this error in script. Can anyone guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the first line of your script?

Comment: Hi Hack- it's #!/bin/ksh

Sorry my bad. I was running the script by using sh filename. it's resolved when i did run with ksh.

Comment: That's the mistake I usually make. Except I usually write Python, so you can imagine the errors I get when I have #!/bin/bash. :)